# Error:error: expected float but got (raw string) match-parent

Tags: android, android-layout

There is almost nothing available about this on the net. How to rectify this error even though all my things are correct. Please help in this !!!

Stuck since 2 days and still din't get any answer.

On clicking the selected part in the screenshot it opens the values.xml file which is huge and definitely I am not going to read that.

Here is the link to the screenshot:

[image: Error message screenshot]

Comment: Post your values.xml

Comment: Or alternatively go to your project folder and delete **app/build** folder and rebuild your project and see if it helps

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in the line

```
<item name="android:layout_weight">match-parent</item>
```

the weight property expects a number, something like this:

```
<item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
```

and if you're trying to set the height and mistakenly chose weight, the value must be either `match_parent` or `wrap_content`, with UNDERSCORE

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Truly appreciate that !! It helped.